# why background color leaks out after clip operator in compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have very simple structure, my question is why there is white border visible, I've tried everything but it's always visible in preview and in runtime

```
               val shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp) 
               Box(
                    modifier = modifier
                        .clip(shape)
                        .border(2.dp, colorResource(id = R.color.blueberry), shape)
                        .background(Color.White)
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "member",
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h1,
                        fontSize = 12.sp,
                        lineHeight = 16.sp,
                        maxLines = 1,
                        color = colorResource(id = R.color.blueberry),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(start = 12.dp, end = 12.dp, top = 2.dp, bottom = 4.dp)
                            .align(Alignment.TopCenter)

                    )
                }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the shape to the background as well to avoid the white border.

```
      Box(modifier = modifier
            .clip(shape)
            .border(2.dp, colorResource(id = R.color.blueberry), shape)
            .background(Color.White, shape) //<- here
      ) { ...
```

Comment: it didn't work perfectly but it helped

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's happening because you are applying `shape` twice and `border` edges do not align perfectly with `clip`. Try a `Surface` instead of the `Box`, it should have better edges.

```
Surface(
    shape = shape,
    border = BorderStroke(2.dp, colorResource(id = R.color.blueberry)),
    color = Color.White,
)
```